# SQL Server 2008 Database Project deployment issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having issue with how to to deploy (a SQL2008 project) to multiple dbs.

I'm using VS2010 + SQL Server 2008 Database project, it imports the "DevDB", works all fine.

Now I want to deploy it to a different DB "TestDB", both DBs are on the same SQL server.

It's keep complained about ".mdf and .log" conflicts.

In SQL 2005 db project, I can just created 2 db connections for deployment, but how to I achieve that in 2008 database project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import your database from the same server you're deploying on, you'll need to edit the yourDB.sqlfile.sql and yourDB_log.sqlfile.sql (in Schema Objects/Databaes Level Objects/Files) and change the references to your database name for all references of the old name, otherwise there is a clash.

See http://continuouslyintegrating.blogspot.com/2009/12/database-already-exists-error-visual.html